# unfamiliar quoting convention in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to debug a bash script on macos. The business end of the script is just:

```
$JAVA_COMMAND $CLASS $*
```

The command line includes /a/b/d/*, where the files in /a/b/d have names in *Arabic*.

When I run with sh -x, each of those files is echoed as $'/a/b/c/*thearabic*'

Where does the $' convention come from, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bash man page:

> Words of the form $'string' are
> treated specially. The word expands to
> string, with backslash-escaped
> characters replaced as specified by
> the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape
> sequences, if present, are decoded as
> follows:
>
> ...
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted,
> as if the dollar sign had not been
> present. A double-quoted string
> preceded by a dollar sign ($) will
> cause the string to be translated
> according to the current locale. If
> the current locale is C or POSIX, the
> dollar sign is ignored. If the string
> is translated and replaced, the
> replacement is double-quoted.

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)